# Add the information from a string to the php filename

Tags: php, html

Hiho,

I would like to be able to add an incremental string to the filename.

e.g. filename.php?increment=1

Is this possible?
I would like to catch the string $increment and use that counter in the page it belongs to.

The main page should fill a list of links, generated from one base php file that gets the incremental counter from the string added tot the filename.

I'll elaborate a bit more ;) It's my first time asking something here and no idea how to ask this properly.

The mainpage should fill with links to one php file.
That one phpfile generates a list of filenames, e.g. img_001.jpg
A variation of that page should be able to create a list like img_001-1.jpg
Where -1 comes from the integer added by the index.php file to filename.php=1

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Is this being done inside `filename.php`? The value of the parameter will be in `$_GET['increment']`. You can add 1 to that to increment it.

Comment: the file adding the increments is index.php that points to filename.php ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the incremented value using php get function which is $_GET

```
<?php
  $increment = isset($_GET['increment']) ? intval($_GET['increment']) : 1;
  echo "Increment value: $increment";
?>
```

For Dynamic link generation then you can use this:

```
<?php
$numLinks = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numLinks; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='filename.php?increment=$i'>Link $i</a><br>";
}
?>
```